# Elasticsearch date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using elasticsearch date histogram aggregation on `@timestamp` field. This is part of the query:

```
'stats': {
    'date_histogram': {
        'field': '@timestamp',
        'interval': '1h',
        'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s'
    }
}
```

and mapping of the `@timestamp`:

```
"@timestamp": {
    "type": "date"
}
```

My time interval is `1h`. But I also need to extract minute information from timestamp without performing aggregation on `1m`. I tried to specify format of the string representation of the key. I got following output:

```
'key_as_string': '2020-11-07 10:0:0'
'key': 1604743200000
```

Is there are way to include minutes in the aggregation results? Either in `key` or `key_as_string`?

One `@timestamp` example indexed in es:

```
'@timestamp': '2020-12-09T13:50:46.056000Z'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Histogram values are [**rounded down**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) to the closest bucket, obeying the formula

```
bucket_key = Math.floor(value / interval) * interval
```

Although it may seem useful to show the exact minutes if you had precisely **one** value in any given bucket but histograms usually *aggregate* a bunch of values and so it does not really make sense to talk about minute-based bucket keys when we're working with hourly intervals.

With that being said, date histograms do accept sub aggregations so if you'd like to retrieve **the individual docs' `@timestamps`** in the desired format, you could utilize a `top_hits` aggregation with `script_fields`:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "stats": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1h",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "concrete_values": {
          "top_hits": {
            "script_fields": {
              "ts_with_minutes": {
                "script": {
                  "source": "LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(doc['@timestamp'].value.millis), ZoneId.of('UTC')).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s'))"
                }
              }
            },
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you might also be interested in the timestamps that come most often, grouped by **minutes** (the seconds are left out from the `format`):

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "stats": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "1h",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "most_represented_timestamps": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd H:m",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found first aggregation useful for my case. But I have 2 questions. Could you explain if it's relevant to the question how the given script works? and performance of given query, how fast/slow it is compared to original aggregation, without sub `aggs`.

Comment: I mean at first glance it executes fast, but I wonder relative to original one?

Comment: You're welcome. Well scripts are notorious for being slow but in this one we're just reading doc values into a java date formatter and spitting out date strings, one at a time. So no significant performance hits, I reckon. I use a few of these in production. As to scripts in general: TL;DR you can execute java-like code on fields and the language is called painless. It's thought to be a last-resort solution but it's perfect for script fields, i.e. transforming field values.

Comment: Thanks again! It really helped.